# Why I am getting undefined while fetching data form API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am a beginner and I am learning JavaScript. I am trying to make some projects with API. I am using Unsplash API to fetch some data. But I am getting type error. In my JavaScript code, lines 4 to 7, I am trying to console.log the likes, views, and downloads but they are showing undefined.

```js
fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?client_id=YILDy9SO8bXBp_dwX7aFO3R_UAs1-8v0gTrK2o2wllE&count=1`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("Likes:", data.likes);
    console.log("Views:", data.views);
    console.log("Downloads:", data.downloads);
});
```

What is the problem? How can I get those values?

Comment: everything with your code seems fine? it's hard to tell since `Rate Limit Exceeded` for this client, maybe that's the reason?

Comment: No. I am getting the problem before the limit is exceeded.

Comment: So what is data? Hard to tell..... If it is undefined, you probably are not referencing right

Comment: Yes, It is showing undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data object returns in an array, so you have to get the 0th element to then access the object and its data. Like this:

```js
fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?client_id=YILDy9SO8bXBp_dwX7aFO3R_UAs1-8v0gTrK2o2wllE&count=1`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("Likes:", data[0].likes);
    console.log("Views:", data[0].views);
    console.log("Downloads:", data[0].downloads);
});
```